# Magento Auto Log Customer In

Tags: magento, autologin

I've searched all around and haven't found a solution for this (or if it's even possible).

I'm running Magento CE 1.9.1

Our store has negotiated pricing for a particular buying group and I'm using Customer Groups to do this.  Not all customers wish to actually place orders online and just want to check on pricing to issue purchase orders.

Is there a way to send customers a link that will auto log them in using a generic account signed to that Customer Group or send them to a CMS Static Page that will log them in?

Comment: You should use this extension : http://shop.partikule.net/en/magento/magento-autologin or you have to create your own module for this. Else I can help you out.

Comment: Thank You, that extension worked wonders.  From download to having a working link in under 5 mins.

Comment: Good. Happy to hear that's worked for you :-). You are welcome John :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sure there could be. Take a look at this example that you can create:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_MyLogMeInController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function myLogMeInAction() {
        $session = Mage::getSinglenton('customer/session');
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            //oops you are already logged in
            //option 1:
            // $this->_redirect('...somewhere...'); 
            // return;
            //option 2:
            // $session->logout();
            // $session->renewSession();
        }
        $groupId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('my_group');
        if ($groupId) {
            $customerId = $this->_myFunctionToRetrievePresetCustomerIdByGroupId($groupId);
            $session->loginById($customerId);
            $session->renewSession();
            $this->_redirect('...wherever i want now that the customer is logged in...');
        } else {
            //oops, invalid request
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }
}
```

One of those `renewSession` calls might be unnecessary, but better safe than sorry.
Also, you might not want to pass the ID directly in the browser if you don't want them to just change that to a 2 instead of a 1, so you could use Magento's encrypt/decrypt for this. See `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::encrypt` and `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::decrypt`.